# ostream << istream and testing EOF on an empty file, alternatives for getting characters from istream

Tags: c++, file-io, get, eof

this is my first post on stackoverflow, so if I'm doing it wrong, please let me know.  I have my final exam for intro C++ programming on wednesday next week, and I have no way of checking my answers to the prof's practice questions.  I'm primarily concerned about checking to see if an input file is empty before copying it's contents to an output file.  Also, grabbing the characters from the input file.  Here's the question and my code below:

Suppose we have the following enumerated type to list possible File I/O errors:

```
enum FileError {
   NoFileError,       // no error detected
   OpenInputError,    // error opening file for input
   OpenOutputError,   // error opening file for output
   UnexpectedFileEnd, // reached end-of-file at unexpected spot in program
   EmptyFileError,    // file contained no data
};
```

Provide appropriate implementations for the three following file handling routines:

```
FileError OpenInputFile(ifstream& infile, char *filename);
// open the named file for input, and return the opening status

FileError OpenOutputFile(ofstream& outfile, char *filename);
// open the named file for output, and return the opening status

FileError CopyNChars(ifstream& infile, ofstream& outfile, int NumChars);
// check to ensure the two files are open,
//    then copy NumChars characters from the input file to the output file
```

Now I'm primarily concerned with the last function listed here. Here's my code:

```
FileError CopyNChars(ifstream& infile, ofstream& outfile, int NumChars){
    char c;
    if (!infile.is_open()) return 1;
    if (!outfile.is_open()) return 2;
    if ((infile.peek()) == -1) return 4; //This right? (I'm using linux with g++ compiler.
    // Also, can I return ints for enum types?
    for (int i = 0; i < NumChars; i++){
        if (infile.eof()) return 3;
        else {
            infile.get(c); //Is this the way to do this?  Or is there another recommendation?
            outfile << c;
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked at various methods for checking the EOF before reading, but I haven't found a SPECIFIC answer for -1 or EOF being a valid check (similar to NULL???).  I think it's just my unfamiliarity with the terminology, because I've looked over the documentation and I can't find an *EXAMPLE* of this kind of check.  Am I doing the empty file check correctly here?  I don't have a driver written to test this code out.  Also, I am concerned about the get method I'm using.  Is there alternatives in this situation, and what's the best way to get one character at a time.  Lastly, am I allowed to ask speculative questions that (like "what are various methods for getting and what's the best in this situation?") on stack overflow.  Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Put your reading into the condition.

Comment: Hi @Robertson I know this is a wrong place to ask, Can you help me out the LDAP config for GitLab?

Comment: @loganathan Sure I can.  aubrey dot viu at gmail dot com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check cplusplus.com. It has some good examples of using ifstream: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/

Particularly, you might want to check out the get() function that has no parameters. It returns EOF if EOF is hit. Also, ifstream has an eof() function that will tell you if he eof bit is set. Also, I don't know if your check of the return value of peek() is guaranteed. CSTDIO defines the EOF macro, which is usually -1, but I don't think that it is guaranteed by the language.

Also, rather than returning integer values, I would return the enum literals. That is what they are there for.